# No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook"

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

i am getting this error when i am using omniauth, devise with rails 3.1.3.I have installed the omniauth gem & omniauth facebook.

Configured the routes.rb as   `match '/auth/:provider/callback',to: 'authentications#create'` asper the guide https://github.com/intridea/omniauth

Whenever i browse the url **http://localhost:3003/auth/facebook/**, i am finding routing error

```
**No route matches [GET] "/auth/facebook"**
```

Please help on this.I have the related post in stackoverflow, and none seems to get worked

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem when using Rails 3.2, OmniAuth 1.0.2 and Devise 2.0.

Apparently there is a problem with the 'path_prefix'. But when manually reconfigured everything works.

Try do this in your initializer:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  configure do |config|
    config.path_prefix = '/auth'
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Without that change I noticed that adding /users before /auth (like /users/auth/facebook) it works. Using same gem versions, was seeing same problem.

Comment: Devise doesn't allow changing the global value of config.path_prefix, but it's possible to set `:path_prefix => '/auth'` in every provider.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and found out that it was caused by :omniauthable devise module. You will need to comment out the module, for example:

```
#app/model/user.rb
def User
    ...
    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
           :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable#, :omniauthable
    ...
end
```

Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 1):

After some hours trying to fix this issue I realized that i'd `config/initializers/omniauth.rb` in the `.gitignore` file (shame on me).

so remove omniauth.rb from the .gitignore list if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because you have configured devise.rb to use scoped_views. Devise's default behavior is to scope out the URL's on your model. The best way to work around that is the use your own controllers, inheriting from Devise's, and telling Devise what controllers and URL's to use. Refer to the [Devise wiki pages](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/) for a more detailed explanation on how to achieve that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

This problem was due to host conflict, we need to make sure, we are changing facebook "Website with Facebook Login"-> Site URL:"" as per production and local development. [image]